# After upgrade from SP2010 to SP2013, picture library thumbnail column no picture show

Tags: 2010, 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, thumbnail

I migrated a SP2010 site to SP2013 farm. After performed the upgrade, everything is fine but we found an image gallery's view not work as expected.

In SP2010 farm, the view have a "Thumbnail" column and shows the shrink-ed version of pictures. After migrate, the view show up same as old one beside the "Thumbnail" column shows nothing. It is just a blank column.

As a test I create a blank new picture library app and add "Thumbnail" column. The column also shows nothing. However, the default "Thumbnail" view (.../Forms/Thumbnails.aspx) shows shrinked pictures in boxes.

I have tested directly browse the thumbnail path http:///PictLib/_t/Chrysanthemum_jpg.jpg. The thumbnail show up!

I checked the Timer job "Upgrade work item" (Processes deferred upgrade work items which were generated during an upgrade. For example, generating thumbnails for upgraded image libraries.) was running daily and last run time is some hours before and the thumbnails still not show.

By using IE8's developer tool I found the blank column have an image element like this one:

```
<img class="ms-displayBlock" id="5webImgShrinked" style="margin: auto; max-width: 128px; visibility: hidden; max-height: 128px;" onerror="displayGenericDocumentIcon(event.srcElement ? event.srcElement : event.target, 0); return false;" onload="(event.srcElement ? event.srcElement : event.target).style.visibility = 'visible';" alt="picture" src="/_layouts/15/images/256_icgen.png" border="0" complete="complete" galleryimg="false"/>
```

What else I can check? Thanks.

Comment: did you try to create another all item view and test it if its work?

Comment: Yes. Create another view seems work

Comment: good to know that works...I added that as an answer, so please mark it as answer so that other get benefits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some time during the migration some views become corrupted especially for picture libraries.

Try to create another View(all items) and test it, If that works then you can delete the default view while making new view as default.